# How can I make jest spied function internally store arguments that the function was called with by deep copy and not by reference

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test a class that is combining fetching, caching, geocoding and returning a list of places. The code that is being tested looks something like this (this is not a full working executable code, but enough to illustrate the problem):

```js
interface Place {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  longitude: number | null;
  latitude: number | null;
}

class Places {
  findAll(country: string): Place[] {
    let places = this.placesCache.get(country)
    if (places === null)
      places = this.placesExternalApiClient.fetchAll(country);
      // BREAKPOINT no.1 (before store() call)
      this.placesCache.store(country, places);
      // BREAKPOINT no.2 (after store() call)
    }
    
    for (const place of places) {
      // BREAKPOINT no.3 (before geocode() call)
      const geocodedAddress = this.geocoder.geocode(place.address);
      place.longitude = geocodedAddress.longitude;
      place.latitude = geocodedAddress.latitude; 
    }  

    return places;
  }
}

class PlacesExternalApiClient {
  fetchAll(country: string): Place[] {
    // makes a request to some external API server, parses results and returns them
  }
}

class PlacesCache {
  store(country: string, places: Place[]) {
    // stores country and places in database with a relation
  }

  get(country: string): Place[] | null {
    // if country is in database, returns all related places (possibly []),
    // if country is not in db, returns null
  }
}

interface GeocodedAddress {
  address: string;
  longitude: number;
  latitude: number;
}

class Geocoder {
  geocode(address: string): GeocodedAddress {
    // makes a request to some geocoding service like Google Geocoder,
    // and returns the best result.
  }
}
```

And this is the test (kinda, illustrates the problem):

```js
mockedPlaces = [
  { name: "place no. 1", address: "Atlantis", longitude: null, latitude: null },
  { name: "place no. 2", address: "Mars base no. 3", longitude: null, latitude: null },
]

mockedPlacesExternalApiClient = {
  fetchAll: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => structuredClone(mockedPlaces))
}

mockedGeocodedAddress = {
  address: "doesn't matter here",
  longitude: 1337,
  latitude: 7331,
}

mockedGeocoder = {
  geocode: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => structuredClone(mockedGeocodedAddress))
}

describe('Places#findAll()', () => {
  it('should call cache#store() once when called two times', () => {
    const storeMethod = jest.spyOn(placesCache, 'store');
    
    places.findAll('abc');
    places.findAll('abc');

    expect(storeMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(storeMethod).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(
      1,
      'abc',
      mockedPlaces, // ERROR: expected places have lng and lat null, null
                    //    but received places have lng and lat 1337, 7331
    );
  })
})
```

I found during debugging that, during first iteration over `places.findAll()` (when there is cache miss):

- on `BREAKPOINT no.1`: `places (var)` has `null` as coordinates
- on `BREAKPOINT no.2`:

  - `places (var)` still has `null` as coordinates
  - `placesCache.store` (which is a `Spied` jest object) has `.mock.calls[0][1]` which is an array where there a two places, both with `null` for lng and lat as expected
- on first hit of `BREAKPOINT no.3`: nothing changed in `.mock.calls` and nothing changed in `places (var)`
- on second hit of `BREAKPOINT no.3`: first place in both arrays: `places (var)` and array  `.mock.calls[0][1]` had changed their coordinates to 1337, 7331!

because of that, later when I ask jest what argument storeMethod was called with, it incorrectly thinks it was called with latitude and longitude 1337, 7331 and not `null`, `null`.

It does not work as I expected it to work because spyOn simply assigns/pushes arguments that it got to `.mock.calls[]`, it does not perform a deep copy, and therefore when the argument is an object that is later mutated, that change is also affecting what the spied object recorded as its call argument.

How can I make spyOn deep clone the arguments it gets?
or, How can I make this test work some other way, without changing the implementation of business logic (first snippet)?

I want to test that `store()` was called with longitude and latitude set to `null`. Now my test gives me a false negative.

Comment: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/434

Comment: @jonrsharpe awesome finding! but seems ticket(and all similar/duplicate) was closed due to inactivity without actually being addressed :(

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh that was the thing I could not find on the internet, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I don't think that mocking specific method of the cache storage gives a value. We normally don't care what exact arguments were passed and how exactly it has been cached. Instead we should care about next cases:

- multiple calls to the fetch method with all the same props makes real call just once and all the times return proper (cached) result
- changing any of meaningful props leads to a separate call and actual result to be returned

But if you still want to implement it your way, what about using `jest.fn` + call to original function?

```
let originalStoreMethod = placesCache.store;
let callsToStoreMethod = [];

beforeEach(() => {
  placesCache.store = jest.fn().mockImplementation((...args) => {
    callsToStoreMethod.push(structuredClone(args));
    return originalStoreMethod.apply(placesCache, args);
  })
});

afterEach(() => {
  placesCache.store = originalStoreMethod;
});

....
    expect(callsToStoreMethod).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(callsToStoreMethod[0]).toEqual(
      1,
      'abc',
      mockedPlaces
    );
```

Comment: Good hints, I have both such tests that you suggested but I also have this one, probably unnecessarily I admit but I think it doesn't hurt my tests suite to have it at least for now. Anyway, that workaround should do the trick nicely, thank you. Also, thanks to @jonrsharpe comment I'm sure there is no build-in jest feature for that.

Comment: @RobertDorna this is out of scope of your question, but I must to say: extra tests which require tricky setup for mocking or/and spying and _does not cover_ some unique case which cannot be tested in other way(you see how I avoided to say "test coverage"? :) ) actually hurt. 

There is direct burden on supporting it and a risk that when things become legitimately broken(e.g. after upgrading some package or internal structure refactoring) it will need enormous of efforts just to understand and recovery this test. Beware!